# What is Animator.Update(float deltaTime) doing?

Tags: unity, c#, animation

It looks like it does the same thing as `Time.timeScale`, only for the Animator. But it works somehow specifically. You need to call each frame for it to work + you can only speed up the animation of the Animator, but not slow it down.

Scaling the playing time of the Animator is easily and clearly carried out through the `Animator.speed`, then why do we need `Animator.Update()`, which for me does not even understand how it works?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Animator.Update()` is a function that you can call to *step* the animator forward by the given interval.

You would use this when the animator is otherwise **paused** (and *not* automatically advancing every frame according to `Time.timeScale` and `Animator.speed`). This lets you take complete control of when the animator should update and by how much. This can also be used ([even with an argument of 0](https://forum.unity.com/threads/forcing-animator-update.381881/#post-3045779)) to nudge the animator and ensure a transition is executed immediately, or sync the bones to their current animated positions to override a ragdoll pose, rather than waiting a frame for it to catch up to the newest gameplay state.

If all you want to do is adjust the animation speed, not take full control of its update loop, then `Animator.speed` is the correct property to use.